# Term order in FREETEXTTABLE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, freetexttable

From the documentation, it seems that SQL Server's FREETEXTTABLE should treat a search query containing multiple words as a bag-of-words.

If I run:

```
SELECT *
FROM FREETEXTTABLE(tblThings, *, 'Cartridge Black')
```

I get results where the word 'Cartridge' is immediately followed by the word 'Black', e.g.:

```
EPSON STYLUS INKJET CARTRIDGE BLACK
INKJET CARTRIDGE BLACK 40ML
```

No results have the words in the other order.

If instead I run

```
SELECT *
FROM FREETEXTTABLE(tblThings, *, 'Black Cartridge')
```

I get a different set of results:

```
AD1020BK BLACK CARTRIDGE
GD230X BLACK CARTRIDGE
```

In neither set of results would I find 'black ink cartridge'.

Is there a way to make SQL Server disregard the order of the words?

Answer (score 0):

Use  freetext  or  conatins

```
SELECT *
FROM FREETEXT(tblThings, *, 'Cartridge Black')
```